# Laravel 5.1 error 404 with route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

somehow when I want to create a new named route in Laravel 5.1 and go to the generated link, I get the 404 page not found error.
does anyone know how to fix this problem? I'll leave the route and the corresponding controller function below.

```
Route::get('article', ["uses" => 'MainController@getArticle', 'as' => 'article']);

public function getArticle()
 {
    return view('pages.article');
 }
```

also, I use wamp 2.5 with a vhost, and the rewrite_module enabled.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake

Comment: try to get rid of the `get` in your method name. so, have `MainController@article` and `public function article()`. also, if you have lots of routes defined try to put this very one right at the top of the `routes.php`. if none works put a closure as a second argument to `Route::get()` and try to dump something out to the screen. see if you can make it work and let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I figured out what I did wrong:
in the httpd-vhosts.conf

```
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
```

while it should've been:

```
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Comment: It may be necessary to enable rewrite mode in Apache by running `a2enmode rewrite`. And restart Apache with `service apache2 restart`. Both as super user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that your `getArticle` method is executed ? (try to die some debug before the `return view..`
2. If your debug is executed, try to check if the view exists.

Considering the code above, le file's name is `article.blade.php` and it is located in the `pages` folder into `resources/views/`

Be sure that when you generate your route, you use:

```
{{ route('article') }}
```

Comment: I checked, and it all is correctly typed, and the route in the href also is correct

Comment: Did you check your config/app.php with the app_url ? (you said you have a vhost)